# Preventing XML External Entity Injection in Soap Based Web Services under JBoss EAP 5.0.1

Tags: xml, jboss, xxe

We are using JBoss EAP 5.0.1 with JBoss WS 3.0.4 and we are trying to find a solution for preventing XML External Entity injection. How to fix this other than upgrading it to a higher version?

Comment: Mel, we are in a similar situation. May I ask how you resolved your XXE concerns?

Answer (score 1):

To prevent entity expansion in exposed RESTEasy XML endpoints, add this to the web.xml:

`<context-param>
    <param-name>resteasy.document.expand.entity.references</param-name>
    <param-value>false</param-value>
</context-param>`

I found this [here](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/TEIID-2911), this issue is related to version 7.7 and 8.4 but may also work for older versions.